# Work on a chain (applications of the integral)

Tags: calculus, integration, applications

A 10-foot-long chain weighs 25 lbs. And hangs from a ceiling. Calculate the work done in raising the lower end of the chain to the ceiling so that it is at the same level as the upper end.

Please, someone from the community can explain or help me with this exercise, I appreciate your time and help.

Comment: Think of conservation of energy. Compute the potential energy of the initial state, and a potential energy of the final state. The difference is a work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may help to visualize this as a differential equation. That is, the change in the amount of work done is dependent on the height of the lower end of the chain. So for every foot the chain is raised ($y$) the work increases by $\frac{2.5}{2}$.
So we can write this as: $$\frac{dW}{dy} = \frac{2.5y}{2}$$
Separating the variables gives us: $$dW = \frac{2.5y}{2} dy$$
Then integrating both sides gives the equation from eng2math in answer $1$.

Answer (score 0):

You can express the weight of the portion you are lifting as a function of the distance it is being raised by, call it $y$. So the work done is
$$
W = \int_{a}^{b} F(y) \,dy
$$
Remark that when you lift the tail of the chain up to the head, you end up with a 'u' shape, so we are lifting a length of $\frac{y}{2}$ feet. So, the chain is $25/10 = 2.5$ pounds per foot so,
$$
W = \int_{0}^{10} 2.5\left(\frac{y}{2}\right) \,dy = 2.5\frac{y^2}{4}\Bigr\rvert_{0}^{10} = 62.5
$$
This might be more appropriate for physics stack exchange, because the trickiness is more physical insight rather than integration.

Comment: I thank you, it is sometimes difficult for me to relate the physical part with this section of the calculation of a variable.